# Finding cell in a row that matches a drop down list

Tags: string, vba, excel, select, rows

I'm a beginner in the art of VBA and all I can do now is record and amend the code based on what I find online. Right now, I am having troubles finding the right formula in finding a cell in a row that matches a drop down list in another excel file.

Suppose file1sheet1 A1 is a drop down list for dates (1-31) and file2sheet1 Row 1 reflects the number of dates (A1 for 1... AE1 for 31), is it possible to select 1 cell down of Row 1 from a column that reflects the date?

Appreciate all the help I can get! Thanks guys!

Cheers!

Mark Sy

Comment: Nearly everything is possible with VBA... But to get our help you must show that you tried something. We're not here to code for you for free, are we?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you just have to search the value of your dropdown list in the other sheet. So you have to ascertain the selected value of the dropdown list at the beginning of your script and then execute a [.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff839746.aspx). And with the returned range of the .Find function you can do whatever you want to.

Comment: Thanks for replying @flohdieter. Can you please show me the formula relative to my needs? Or you can just drop an example and I'll figure it out to the best that I can. Thank you!